# PDFSharp: Measuring height of long text with word wrap

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfsharp

PDFSharp supports automatic text wrapping when drawing long text portions:

```
textFormatter.DrawString(text, font, XBrushes.Black, new XRect(x, y, textAreaWidth, 1000), XStringFormats.TopLeft);
```

This will wrap the text if it is longer than `textAreaWidth`.

How can I get the height of the text that has just been drawn?

I tried it with `gfx.MeasureString()`, but there is no overload that supports specifying a maximal width. `gfx.MeasureString()` returns the size of the text without text wrapping.

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: If a single page is not enough and you may need more pages, then better switch to MigraDoc directly.
If you are sure a single page will be enough for all times, just add an out parameter to XTextFormatter.DrawString that returns the height of the text that was just drawn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this extension of PdfSharp to be the answer to this problem:

http://developer.th-soft.com/developer/2015/07/17/pdfsharp-improving-the-xtextformatter-class-measuring-the-height-of-the-text/

You can clone or fork the relevant code here:

https://github.com/yolpsoftware/PdfSharp/tree/measure-text-height

Answer (score 10):

This extension of PdfSharp didn't quite work for me. Don't know why but i was keeping getting a bigger height than expected (almost the double of the neededHeight). So I decided to write an extension method the the XGraphics object where i can specify a maxWidth and internally calculate the soft line breaks.
The code uses the default `XGraphics.MeasureString(string, XFont)` to the inlined text Width and Aggregates with the words from the text to calclulate the Line breaks.
The code to calculate the soft Line breaks looks like this :

```
/// <summary>
/// Calculate the number of soft line breaks
/// </summary>
private static int GetSplittedLineCount(this XGraphics gfx, string content, XFont font, double maxWidth)
{
    //handy function for creating list of string
    Func<string, IList<string>> listFor = val => new List<string> { val };
    // string.IsNullOrEmpty is too long :p
    Func <string, bool> nOe = str => string.IsNullOrEmpty(str);
    // return a space for an empty string (sIe = Space if Empty)
    Func<string, string> sIe = str => nOe(str) ? " " : str;
    // check if we can fit a text in the maxWidth
    Func<string, string, bool> canFitText = (t1, t2) => gfx.MeasureString($"{(nOe(t1) ? "" : $"{t1} ")}{sIe(t2)}", font).Width <= maxWidth;

    Func<IList<string>, string, IList<string>> appendtoLast =
            (list, val) => list.Take(list.Count - 1)
                               .Concat(listFor($"{(nOe(list.Last()) ? "" : $"{list.Last()} ")}{sIe(val)}"))
                               .ToList();

    var splitted = content.Split(' ');

    var lines = splitted.Aggregate(listFor(""),
            (lfeed, next) => canFitText(lfeed.Last(), next) ? appendtoLast(lfeed, next) : lfeed.Concat(listFor(next)).ToList(),
            list => list.Count());

    return lines;
}
```

See the following Gist for the complete code : https://gist.github.com/erichillah/d198f4a1c9e8f7df0739b955b245512a

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me, though I don't completely understand the code.  I'm a bit new at C#, maybe that's why.

Comment: This works great to return the number of lines, but is there a way to determine the height of each line?

Comment: Man, you saved my days..thanks a lot, works great! Update: PrepareDrawString as recommended in other answers also sounds promising

Answer (score 4):

The XTextFormatter class (source code included with PDFsharp) is meant to get you started. Modify it if it doesn't suit your needs.

Since XTextFormatter keeps the Y position internally, it would be a rather simple change to return the height of the text that was just drawn.

Instead of modifying XTextFormatter, consider using MigraDoc Foundation (also included) instead.