# Measuring Text Height within a rectangle PDFsharp

Tags: c#, .net, pdfsharp

I am trying to layout a PDF document using `PDFsharp`. I'm wondering how to return the height of text after it is wrapped within a rectangle. So that I can draw a string immediately under the previous string.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

```
private static readonly XRect LeftRect = new XRect(10, 45, 290, 370);

public static void BuildLeftRect(this XGraphics gfx)
{
    var tf = new XTextFormatter(gfx);
    gfx.DrawRectangle(XPens.Black, LeftRect);
    tf.DrawString(GenerateAVeryLongString(), HeadingFont, XBrushes.Black, LeftRect, XStringFormats.TopLeft);
    var textMeasurement = gfx.MeasureString(GenerateAddressesText(), TextFont);
    //I want to write another string here, but the height of text measurement is the font size, not the wrapped text size. 
    Console.WriteLine(textMeasurement);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It wasn't all that difficult, I wrote this helper function in case someone else needs it.

```
private static double GetTextHeight(this XGraphics gfx, string text, double rectWidth)
        {
            var fontHeight = TextFont.GetHeight();
            var absoluteTextHeight = gfx.MeasureString(text, TextFont).Height;
            var absoluteTextWidth = gfx.MeasureString(text, TextFont).Width;

            if (absoluteTextWidth > rectWidth)
            {
                var linesToAdd = (int)Math.Ceiling(absoluteTextWidth / 290) - 1;
                return absoluteTextHeight + linesToAdd * (fontHeight);
            }
            return absoluteTextHeight;
        }
```

You would call like so: `var heightAfterWrappedInRect = gfx.GetTextHeight("text", rectWidth)`

Comment: No need to call gfx.MeasureString twice - call it once and assign result to a variable. What's the purpose of the literal "290"?

Comment: It's the absolute width of the column.

Comment: I expected that. Why don't you use rectWidth instead of 290? With linebreaks occurring between words only, this simple calculation will not always work. So adding an out parameter to XTextFormatter will be the better, more general solution. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15478864/1015447